# SCE Editor not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem, when I make changes to my text I'm getting this plain html code in my article:
`[size=7][font=Comic Sans MS]TEXT[/font][/size]` can someone tell me why this is not working ? I'm output data like this: `{!!$article->body!!}`

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. The tags are wrong. Tags should be between `<></>` and not between `[][/]`